# How to avoid MissingMethodException using nugets?

Tags: c#, nuget, version

I'm creating nugets with all my C# project, and therefore replacing all direct references to csproj files. All the nuget references are "Minimum version, inclusive", so when a library is updated, all other projects will automatically restore the latest version of that nuget. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to ensure that a change in a nuget won't make the compilation fail in other projects. Up until now, I used to build all the projects in a single solution, so if something failed to compile, I'd know it right away. Now that I'm using nugets, I end up introducing new bugs because I can't make sure the code still compiles, or even worse, if the code will run at all, be cause it may crash.

Here's an example:

- Application "App" refers to nuget library "LibA"
- Project "LibA" refers to nuget "LibB"
- A hotfix is published in project "LibB", so the new nuget is published.
- This hotfix makes it impossible to build "LibA", because by accident a method was removed. But no one tries to build "LibA", so nobody notices it.
- Someone builds "App", and the compilation works fine because "App" does not refer directly to the missing method in "LibB". Hence, the problem will only occur at runtime, when "LibA" tries to call the missing method.

I understand that I could use a more strict versionning to accomplish this, so that when a nuget change, I would need to change all the references and so a new build would be required for all other projects to use this new version of the library. But that does not seem handy if it means I need to modify systematically hundreds of projects just to push a bug fix in a single library.

Comment: Then your requirements prevent you from changing Method Signatures. Method implementations can always change. But no signature can be removed, without breaking code. At best you can now mark functions as "Deprecated". Basically the same situation the .NET Framework and every library before it have been in.

Comment: The problem is : how to enforce it ? Is it possible to create a policy to prohibite changes that remove public methods ?
Also, suppose someone adds something in the code that breaks the compilation (ex : a method extension that already exist in another assembly), how to prevent this, and/or how to make sure we catch the problem before the code is released ?

Comment: From what i understand this leads to a whole concept of UnitTesting, Continuous Integration or even Gated Check In

Comment: I'm dealing with code legacy. I foresee that in 5 years I might be able to rely massively on unittesting to make the individual libraries relyable. In the meantime, I have to deal with all sort of problem like this one. I barely have tests, everything is public, a small change can introduce all kind of compilation errors. I need a solution for my long transition. I don't even wish to prevent errors. I just wish I could at least catch them fast, at low cost. I can't afford a full rebuild of all my nugets each time a single change is made.

Comment: I'm almost certain it's technically possible to analyse the content of a dll in order to check if the references to all the external method/properties are still valid. I just don't know how to do it. If it's possible, I could run a routine that validates all my dlls, which would take a fraction of the time it would require to actually rebuild the projects.

Comment: The only thing you can really do is don't use "Minimum version, inclusive". You want to be able to control how/when changes are introduced. Otherwise, what's the point of switching to packages? This also assumes that the teams building LibA and LibB properly increment their package versions when they introduce breaking changes. The standard practice is to increase the major version when there's a breaking change, but increase the minor version when there are non-breaking changes.

Comment: The idea to use packages was in order to improved the performance of the team, because working with hundreds of projects in one solution file makes it impossible to work in visual studio. We tried to split the solution, but then many projects needed to be in all the solutions, and it became very difficult to handle. Also, it's faster to deploy with packages, we don't need to rebuild everything all the time.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to detect missing methods by forcing JIT compilation of your methods.

For that you just need enumerate all methods in your assemblies using reflection and then call `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle)` for each of them.

The tricky part here is dealing with generics. If your method or class contains generics, you also need to specify the concrete types for which your generic method will be jitted:

```
Type[] classGenericArgs = ...;
Type[] methodGenericArgs = ...;
Type[] allGenericArgs = classGenericArgs.Concat(methodGenericArgs).ToArray();
RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle, allGenericArgs.Select(p => p.TypeHandle).ToArray());`
```

If your generic arguments also have constraints, you need to make sure that the types you choose satisfy these constraints, otherwise, jitting will fail.

Satisfying constraints can be difficult, so I wrote a Jitter class to automate this. It forces load of all libraries referenced by your application into memory and runs jitting with automatically substituting appropriate concrete classes for your generic methods (if possible). The usage for it is simple, just specify which assemblies you want jitted:

```
Jitter.RunJitting(asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("My.Company.Namespace"));
```

Put this line in your Startup.cs or Program.cs to make missing methods apparent. Make sure your .NET app references all assemblies you want to verify.

You can find the source code for Jitter [here](https://github.com/oleksiizamyslov/samples/blob/main/Jitter.cs). It is far from perfect, but is able to jit 99.8% of all methods in our codebase and detect broken package dependencies for us.

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.